# Configuring autotools to use the same object files to build two programs

Tags: automake, catch2

I have a C++ project using autotools to build, and [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) for unit testing. The details of Catch2 are probably not relevant: it's just another program I have to build and run.

I have `Makefile.am` set up like this (simplified):

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects
check_PROGRAMS = catch2
bin_PROGRAMS = lpsdr

common_sources = applicationcontroller.cc flowgraph.cc [...]
lpsdr_SOURCES = $(common_sources) main.cc
catch2_SOURCES = $(common_sources) test.cc
```

This works mostly, except it compiles everything twice, creating `lpsdr-applicationcontroller.o` and `catch2-applicationcontroller.o`, and so on for each thing in `common_sources`.

Of course this doubles the build time. I'd prefer to link both `catch2` and `lpsdr` with the same object files: it will be faster to build and also ensure I'm testing exactly the same compiled code as I'm running.

Is there any way around this behavior?

Comment: Simplifying the Makefile.am may remove some important details.  If the programs have different compiler flags, then Automake will make separate objects, because that's what you asked for.

Comment: @TomTromey Are you saying if the flags are identical, automake won't do that? The project is on github, https://github.com/bitglue/lpsdr_software/blob/98884b2f355682d2743aca5663b663b0a6d2bcf0/src/Makefile.am is the makefile just before I added check2. I never pushed the broken version but perhaps you can make some guesses at how I did it. Mostly I just added `catch2_CXXFLAGS = $(lpsdr_CXXFLAGS)`, etc.

Comment: IIRC it doesn't try to check whether the flags are identical, but instead just relies on the presence or absence of per-"aggregate" flags.  In your case you have `lpsdr_CXXFLAGS`, so that's enough.  If you want that to apply to all the objects, just rename it to `AM_CXXFLAGS`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a way to avoid building distinct object files for each program, but the same effect can be had by [building an intermediate static library](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/A-Library.html#A-Library), and then linking `lpsdr` and `catch2` against that.

Something like this:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects

noinst_LIBRARIES = liblpsdr.a
check_PROGRAMS = catch2
bin_PROGRAMS = lpsdr

liblpsdr_a_SOURCES = applicationcontroller.cc dispatcher_sink.cc [...]

lpsdr_SOURCES = main.cc
lpsdr_LDADD = liblpsdr.a
catch2_SOURCES = test.cc
catch2_LDADD = liblpsdr.a
```